# feature selection for classification for rare classes

Tags: spectrogram, classification, feature-extraction

I have a spectrogram of a signal and want to classify it. I used different features such as MFFC, the density of power spectrum and other common features and classify using the random forest, but I did not get good results.

I think that my features are not well selected and I guess that there is no relation between my aimed classes and the selected features.
my classes are so rare.

could anyone suggest a way for obtaining features?(for very rare data)
also, I used some methods of feature extraction from biological images, but I think that the data are different. my data are double and those are some 3 dimensions data.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of [Arizona State - Feature Selection Algorithms](https://jundongl.github.io/scikit-feature/OLD/algorithms_old.html) for feature selection:

```
BLogReg  
CFS  
Chi Square  
FCBF  
Fisher Score  
Gini Index  
Information Gain  
Kruskal-Wallis  
mRMR  
Relief-F  
SBMLR  
T-test  
SPEC
```

Comment: Link-only answers aren't all that great. Could you please add a few bullet points to your answer, listing the algorithms from the link?

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Comment: @EricJohnson https://jundongl.github.io/scikit-feature/OLD/algorithms_old.html